# Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: bosauthsmtp05: Host 117.58.242.18: No unauthenticated relaying permitted

Tags: asp.net

An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ava9W.png)
Additional information: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: bosauthsmtp05: Host 117.58.242.18: No unauthenticated relaying permitted

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Farhad! When you ask a question make sure you provide the relevant code that is causing this error so we can help you further.

Comment: Ok.. i am trying to send mail from my asp,net project. i can send mail by using  gamil or yahoo-ex, hfarhadh033@gmail.com or gctlpos@yahoo.com. but i have a mail account in iPage server like farhad@gctlbd.com.. when i try to send mail by using ipage mail server ...then exception occur....

Comment: When asking a question on SO you include the relevant code in your question so others can see what your problem is too, contributors don't access code via email. As a follow up, you can edit your question to place the code within a code box. (e.g. `function X() { ... // code here }` )

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
string to = "receiver@domain.com";

    //It seems, your mail server demands to use the same email-id in SENDER as with which you're authenticating. 
    //string from = "sender@domain.com";
    string from = "test@domain.com";

    string subject = "Hello World!";
    string body =  "Hello Body!";
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.domain.com");
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test@domain.com", "password");
    client.Send(message);
```